# Creating coupon using Charge 2 plugin

Tags: plugins, error-message, mysql, plugin-charge

I just updated the Charge 2 plugin to latest (version 2.2.1) and when I try to create a new coupon, I get this error:

```
CDbException
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'amountOff' at row 1.
```

I've tried various scenarios; entering a fixed amount for the coupon, a percentage amount as well as trying various payment types, and it gives the same error above, regardless of whether I choose a fixed or percentage amount.

Has anyone else ran into this issue and if so, have you figured out a solution for it?

I also tried reverting back to previous versions of the plugin, and I get the same error. That last version that worked with coupons was Charge 2.1.8.

I'm running Craft 2.6.2997, PHP 7.1, MySQL 5.7.2.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question since it seems to be a plugin related bug. Unless you want to try to fix it in the code by yourself you should rather contact the developer. I could be totally wrong but my guess is: the value is not populated correctly or gets lost during the process. You could check the code step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. There are some posts with tags 'plugin' and 'plugin-charge' that have some helpful answers, so I was hoping for similar results. [link](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-charge) 
I contacted the developer regarding this & other issues but have yet to hear back. Not sure if it's still being actively developed, unfortunately. Also tried stepping through the plugin code & db to try to make sense but no luck yet. I will keep trying. In the meantime, hoping perhaps someone else out there has encountered this as well & has a solution.